# Translation Manager sends parent components not localised children - for v1 components

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

We've noted some odd behaviour when using Translation Manager to send jobs to TMS.
This is the simplified blueprint:

- 200 Global EN (id 234)
- 400 Local EN-RU (id 262)
- 500 Translation RU-RU (id 279)

*400 Local EN-RU* is set as a source publication and *500 Translation RU-RU* a target publication for Translation Manager purposes - we're using SDL TMS for translation.

What we've noticed is the following:

1. Created global English components at 200 Global EN. These are at v1.
2. Localised these components at 400 Local EN-RU. Update a localised component so it was at v2.
3. Created a bundle at 400 Local EN-RU. Added all (v1 & v2) localised components. Send that bundle for translation.
4. When we look in TMS we can see filenames for components. The localised v2 components have the 400 Local EN-RU publications id in the filename, e.g. **tcm_262-224386_Test.cmp** - but the localised v1 components have the parent publication id in the filename are actually from the parent publication 200 Global EN, e.g. **tcm_234-224386_Test.cmp** despite being localised!

This seems like a bug - why is Translation Manager ignoring the localised v1 component at 400 Local EN-RU and sending the parent 200 Global EN content instead - except for when the component is v2?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ignores v1.0 components because they are always identical to the parent (as it was at the time you localized), and therefore in the language of the parent.

For example, let's say you translate Japanese > English > Swedish

When you localize your Japanese component in the English publication you get a v1 component. This component will contain Japanese text, and therefore translation manager will not accept it for an English to Swedish translation job. It's not checking the text, just the version - so as long a version 1.1 or 2.0 is available, it will assume it is now English, even if you did not change any text.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Can this behaviour be changed through any event code for instance?  This has cropped up with a client where a parent component was changed after a child was localised to remove text - the client was expecting the child component to be sent for translation (inc. this text) but this behaviour means the parent was sent and therefore the translation for the text in the child was missed.

Comment: It should be possible to overwrite in the resolver event of translation manager.

Comment: So, just to confirm (to you both), if we... [1] Create a component in 200 Global EN...  [2] Localise this component in 400 Local EN-RU... [3] Update the parent 200 Global EN component (to v2)... [4] Send the 400 Local EN-RU component (still localised as v1) to translation...... then it would still send the (updated) v2 version of the 200 Global EN component, because the 400 Local EN-RU component hasn't been amended? Is that correct?

Comment: From memory, yes that is what I would expect. I no longer have access to Tridion, so can't verify it.

Comment: Super. Thanks for confirming @LarsMøllebjerg